# Encoding error when extracting korean text from a xml file into a csv file

Tags: python, csv, encoding

I have to extract information from several xml files and some of them contain information in Korean. The file has the following structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root _ID="999" _Status="Closed">
    <Name>Big tech</Name>
    <LegalName>Big tech Inc.</LegalName>
    <Comments> 섹터와 지역에 따라 대표적인 기업과 내재가치 대비 저평가</Comments>
    ....
</Root>
```

My code is as follows:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Company=open('Company.csv', 'w')

tree = ET.parse(xmlpath, parser=ET.XMLParser(encoding="utf-8"))#parserx=ET.XMLParser(encoding="cp949")
root = tree.getroot()
name=root.find('Name').text
legalname=root.find('LegalName').text
comments=root.find('Comments').text


Company.write('Name; LegalName;Comments;\n')
Company.write('{}; {}; {}\n'.format(name, legalname, comments))
Company.close()
```

The error that I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ET.py", line 226, in <module>
    Company.write('{}; {}; {}\n'.format(name, legalname, comments))
  File "C:\Users\*****\*****\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings
\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position *2-**4:
 character maps to <undefined>
```

When I use the following line:

```
comments=comments.encode('utf-8')
```

The csv records this instead of the korean characters:

```
b'\xec\x84\xb9\xed\x84\xb0\xec\x99\x80 \xec\xa7\x80\xec\x97\xad\xec\x97\x90 \xeb
\x94\xb0\xeb\x9d\xbc \xeb\x8c\x80\xed\x91\x9c\xec\xa0\x81\xec\x9d\xb8 \xea\xb8\x
b0\xec\x97\x85\xea\xb3\xbc \xeb\x82\xb4\xec\x9e\xac\xea\xb0\x80\xec\xb9\x98 \xeb
\x8c\x80\xeb\xb9\x84 \xec\xa0\x80\xed\x8f\x89\xea\xb0\x80'
```

I've already tried comments=comments.encode('utf-8').decode('utf-8') and with all combinations of encode and decode (with utf-8, cp1252, euc_kr and cp949) without success, whenever I tried to add the line to the csv file, I'm always getting the previous error. There is no errors when the xml doesn't contain korean characters.

Comment: `Company=open('Company.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')` - you want to have the right encoding on the output file.

Comment: Not sure if this was a misprint but in `legalname=root.find('LegalnName').text
`, `LegalnName` should be `LegalName`. When I changed that it worked: https://onlinegdb.com/HJ6kr8hor

Comment: Thank you  @snakecharmerb , I though open function would be using utf-8 by default, it works perfectly now.

Comment: @roasty Thank you and indeed it was a misprint, the xml files and larger and with a different structure. The real issue was not defining the encoding for the output file as stated by snakecharmerb  .

Comment: The default encoding of text files is the result of calling [locale.getpreferredencoding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/locale.html#locale.getpreferredencoding)